# Why the addition group of a local field is isomorphic to its character group?

Tags: number-theory, topological-groups, local-field, locally-compact-groups

In Tate's thesis, he claims that for a local field $k$ and any non-trivial character $\chi$ of its addition group $k^+$, the correspondence $\eta\mapsto\chi(\eta\xi)$ is an isomorphism, both topological and algebraic, between $k^+$ and its character group.

He uses 6 steps to prove this, and what is confusing me is in the fourth, where he shows the image of the correspondence is everywhere dense in the character group. He says $\chi(\eta\xi)=1\text{ for any }\eta\Rightarrow\xi=0$, but I cannot find the relation with this fact and the density of the image.

Comment: What is the topology on the character group of $k^+$ ?

Comment: The compact-open topology

Comment: The answer is reasonable, but i think the use of Pontryagin's theorem is a little bit unacceptable. That proof supplements too much details, and i don't think it is the original purpose of Tate. There must be a direct and simple connection.

Comment: Ok. I don't have an aswer to your interesting question yet, but it reminds me now of [my own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3407821/existence-of-a-non-trivial-additive-character-on-a-non-archimedian-local-field) about 3 years ago on this website. In Bushnell and Henniart's book, Proposition of paragraph 1.7, they prove that the map $k\rightarrow \widehat{k}$ from $k$ to its character group defined the same way as yours is a group isomorphism ; however they don't show that it's a homeomorphism. Their argument may be interesting to you, hopefully.